# build constraints exclude all Go files when installing OpenTofu

Tags: go, terraform, opentofu

When I use command `go build .` to install OpenTofu on Windows 10 and wsl.

It said

```
package github.com/opentofu/opentofu: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/trung/opentofu
```

Before it, I just git clone from github. What can I do to fix it?

I searched online but still don't see any similar case.

Comment: Have you followed the [BUILDING](https://github.com/opentofu/opentofu/blob/main/BUILDING.md) guide. What go version are you using?

Comment: Looking at that repo, the root directory only has files with `tools` build constraints, and no main package. You need to build the main package from a different directory (which is probably covered the BUILDING documentation)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to run `go build` in the `cmd/tofu` subdirectory of the repository, which contains the main function.

Comment: Problem solved, Thank you Cube